# How do I create vintage images in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

Given a colour image as input, I would like to superimpose 3 images of the same size with the following colors: Green, black and blue.

For each of these images, I would like to change their opacity:

- Green = 40%
- Black = 43%
- Blue = 39%

Once I create these images, I would like to finally overlay the input image image with opacity of 38%.  Can anyone help?  I would like to take the original image and apply this vintage effect using MATLAB.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried, but with poor results. Do you think my idea to get a vintage image in this way, do you think that is possible?

Comment: I know how to create vintage images, but not in the way you're asking.  I've never dealt with vintage images using opacities of those three colours.  I've created vintage / sepia images using a weighted combination of the RGB components for each channel.  Do you want me to write an answer with my method?

Comment: Yes, I would be grateful. :) My idea was to create the same effect using instagram.

Comment: Cool :) Give me one moment.

Answer (score 4):

I've never created sepia / vintage like effects on an image using the opacities that you speak of.  What I usually do to create sepia / vintage images is to create the output red, green and blue components using a combination of the input image's red, green and blue channels.

How you create sepia / vintage images in this way is by using the following equations.  Supposing that your red, green and blue channels for your input image are stored in `inputRed`, `inputGreen`, and `inputBlue` respectively.  These are the equations recommended by [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com):

```
outputRed = (inputRed * .393) + (inputGreen *.769) + (inputBlue * .189)
outputGreen = (inputRed * .349) + (inputGreen *.686) + (inputBlue * .168)
outputBlue = (inputRed * .272) + (inputGreen *.534) + (inputBlue * .131)
```

<sup>Source: [Tech Republic](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/how-do-i/how-do-i-convert-images-to-grayscale-and-sepia-tone-using-c/)</sup>

`outputRed`, `outputGreen`, `outputBlue` are the output colour channels for the sepia / vintage image.  As such, simply read in your image, then extract each of the colour planes, do this weighted combination for each of the output colour channels, then combine the channels together.  It should be noted that when you read in the image, this will most likely be of a `uint8` type.  To keep the precision when multiplying with decimal numbers, you need to cast the image to `double` before proceeding.  Once you calculate the sepia / vintage channels,  you'll need to cast the result back to `uint8` so you can properly display the image as well as save it to disk.  As such, here's the code:

```
im = double(imread('...')); % // Read in your image here
inputRed = im(:,:,1); %// Extract each colour plane
inputGreen = im(:,:,2);
inputBlue = im(:,:,3);

%// Create sepia tones for each channel
outputRed = (inputRed * .393) + (inputGreen *.769) + (inputBlue * .189);
outputGreen = (inputRed * .349) + (inputGreen *.686) + (inputBlue * .168);
outputBlue = (inputRed * .272) + (inputGreen *.534) + (inputBlue * .131);

%// Create output image by putting all of these back into a 3D matrix
%// and convert back to uint8
out = uint8(cat(3, outputRed, outputGreen, outputBlue));

figure;
imshow(im,[]); %// Show original image
figure;
imshow(out); %// Show sepia image
```

Take note that to create the 3D matrix again, I use [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) which concatenates arrays / matrices in a specified dimension.  I specified the third dimension, as we want to stack the red, green and blue channels on top of each other to form a 3D matrix.  I then cast this result to `uint8`.

---

Here's an example.  I decided to take a family portrait from [Jon Woodbury Photography](http://jonwoodburyphotography.com).  Those who are appearing here I don't know personally, but thanks for letting me use your picture nonetheless :)

http://jonwoodburyphotography.com/blog/wp-content/gallery/12-best-family-portraits-of-2012/best-unique-family-portraits-utah-8544.jpg

When I download this image, then run the code with this image, this is the output I get:

[image]

---

## Sidenote - Efficiency

The code above is quite a lot to type out.  You can do this in two lines (three if you consider reading in the image as a step) if you wish by using a combination of [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) and [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html).  You would need to encapsulate the sepia coefficients in a 2D matrix, then you can calculate each output pixel as a matrix multiplication.  As such:

```
im = double(imread('...')); %// Read in image
%// Define sepia matrix
M = [0.393 0.769 0.189; 0.349 0.686 0.168; 0.272 0.534 0.131];
out = uint8(reshape((M*reshape(permute(im, [3 1 2]), 3, [])).', ...
           [size(im,1) size(im,2), 3]));
```

You should get the same thing in the output as with the previous version of the code!  As a test, you provided an image in the comments below:

[image]

This is what I get using the modified code (really, you'll just get the same results like the first version of the code):

[image]

Comment: Thank you. :) P.S. you think to get an effect as well as you could do. http://i.ytimg.com/vi/14khxLI8j4U/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: @angel - I'm sorry? What would you like done with that image?  Do you want to find what the vintage of this looks like?  Either way, I did it for you.  Check my edited post.

Comment: Meanwhile, thank you for availability. I'd like to apply effects like the image that I have posted.

Comment: Let me explain. a) http://i46.photobucket.com/albums/f137/thanhtu_zx/Untitled-1.jpg
b) http://i.ytimg.com/vi/14khxLI8j4U/maxresdefault.jpg
Take into consideration the figure a) the first part eg for a1) I would like to apply a filter as such the figure b).

Comment: @angel - That I can't replicate.  Those are trade secrets to instagram, which is why they make money on their app :) If the exact algorithm was available, then instagram wouldn't make any money :).  Here's where I can't help you.  The closest you can get to vintage / sepia is what I have above.  Sorry!  Good luck btw.