# Color correcting images in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have 2 images `im1` and `im2` shown below.  The`im2` picture is the same as `im1`, but the only difference between them is the colors. `im1` has RGB ranges of (0-255, 0-255, 0-255) for each color channel while `im2` has RGB ranges of (201-255, 126-255, 140-255). My exercise is to reverse the added effects so I can restore `im2` to `im1` as closely as I can. I have 2 thoughts in mind. The first is to match their histograms so they both have the same colors. I tried it using `histeq` but it restores only a portion of the image. Is there any way to change `im2`'s histogram to be exactly the same as `im1`? The second approach was just to copy each pixel value from `im1` to `im2` but this is wrong since it doesn't restore the original image state. Are there any suggestions to restore the image?

[image]

[image]

Comment: can't you use linear mapping between `color1` and `color2`?

Comment: when you say linear mapping you mean for each pixel value of im2 matrix copy it to im1? This is just copy paste or not ?

Comment: No, You get a value from `im2` like `r=220`. And you want to map it into a value in range `im1`. You can map it by making a linear equation. it is not copy-paste.

Comment: wow thanks dude,can you explain me what you mean by linear equation?If i am not wrong mapping is for pixel at im1(1,1,1) should be the same color as pixel of im2 at (1,1,1) ?

Comment: Is this correct ?                                                            for i = 1 : 640                                                                     for j = 1 : 480                                                                     for rgb = 1 : 3                                                                          im2(i,j,rgb) = im1(i.j,rgb);                                                      end                                                                                end                                                                               end

Comment: @KostasRim - No.  You're simply copying the colours from `im1` to `im2`.  I'll write an answer.

Comment: @KostasRim - In hindsight it doesn't look like it's possible.  The linear mapping and all of what we have tried assume a 1-to-1 mapping between colours from `im2` to `im1`.  Looking at the histograms, there is **more than one** colour in `im2` that maps to `im1`... so in hindsight, doing a complete reversal is not possible.  I have one more thing I'm going to try, which is trying to find the correct transformation by minimizing by least-squares, but it will definitely not be as simple as doing a linear mapping.

Comment: Don't try it, the exercise says as close as you can. I though that you could reverse it at 100% but i was wrong. Thanks again for your help and your time. Have a happy new year:)

Comment: @KostasRim - My pleasure :) Well I did get something... and the colours are close, but the composition is way off.  If you like, I can update my answer to show you.

Comment: if you have time to update it yeah :)

Comment: OK! I will very soon. Thanks!

Comment: @KostasRim - Done.  Check my edits!  Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@sepdek below pretty much suggested the method that @NKN alluded to, but I will provide another approach.  One more alternative I can suggest is to perform a colour correction based on a least mean squared solution.  What this alludes to is that we can assume that transforming a pixel from `im2` to `im1` requires a linear combination of weights.  In other words, given a RGB pixel where its red, green and blue components are shaped into a 3 x 1 vector from the corrupted image (`im2`), there exists some linear transformation to get its equivalent pixel in the clean image (`im1`).  In other words, we have this relationship:

```
[R_im1]       [R_im2]
[G_im1] = A * [G_im2]
[B_im1]       [B_im2]

  Y     = A *   X
```

`A` in this case would be a 3 x 3 matrix.  This is essentially performing a matrix multiplication to get your output corrected pixel.  The input RGB pixel from `im2` would be `X` and the output RGB pixel from `im1` would be `Y`.  We can extend this to as many pixels as we want, where pairs of pixels from `im1` and `im2` would establish columns along `Y` and `X`.  In general, this would further extend `X` and `Y` to `3 x N` matrices.  To find the matrix `A`, you would find the least mean squared error solution.  I won't get into it, but to find the optimal matrix of `A`, this requires finding the pseudo-inverse.  In our case here, `A` would thus equal to:

[image]

Once you find this matrix `A`, you would need to take each pixel in your image, shape it so that it becomes a 3 x 1 vector, then multiply `A` with this vector like the approach above.  One thing you're probably asking yourself is what kinds of pixels do I need to grab from both images to make the above approach work?  One guideline you must adhere to is that you need to make sure that you're sampling from **the same spatial location** between the two images.  As such, if we were to grab a pixel at... say... row 4, column 9, you need to make sure that both pixels from `im1` and `im2` come from this same row and same column, and they are placed in the same corresponding columns in `X` and `Y`.

Another small caveat with this approach is that you need to be sure that you sample a lot of pixels in the image to get a good solution, and you also need to make sure the spread of your sampling is over the entire image.  If we localize the sampling to be within a small area, then you're not getting a good enough distribution of the colours and so the output will not look very nice.  It's up to you on how many pixels you choose for the problem, but from experience, you get to a point where the output starts to plateau and you don't see any difference.  For demonstration purposes, I chose 2000 pixels in random positions throughout the image.

As such, this is what the code would look like.  I use [`randperm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) to generate a random permutation from 1 to `M` where `M` is the total number of pixels in the image.  These generate linear indices so that we can sample from the images and construct our matrices.  We then apply the above equation to find `A`, then take each pixel and apply a matrix multiplication with `A` to get the output.  Without further ado:

```
close all;
clear all;
im1 = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtgHU.jpg');
im2 = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHW50.jpg');

rng(123); %// Set seed for reproducibility
num_colours = 2000;
ind = randperm(numel(im1) / size(im1,3), num_colours);

%// Grab colours from original image
red_out = im1(:,:,1);
green_out = im1(:,:,2);
blue_out = im1(:,:,3);

%// Grab colours from corrupted image
red_in = im2(:,:,1);
green_in = im2(:,:,2);
blue_in = im2(:,:,3);

%// Create 3 x N matrices
X = double([red_in(ind); green_in(ind); blue_in(ind)]);
Y = double([red_out(ind); green_out(ind); blue_out(ind)]);

%// Find A
A = Y*(X.')/(X*X.');

%// Cast im2 to double for precision
im2_double = double(im2);

%// Apply matrix multiplication    
out = cast(reshape((A*reshape(permute(im2_double, [3 1 2]), 3, [])).', ...
          [size(im2_double,1) size(im2_double,2), 3]), class(im2));
```

---

Let's go through this code slowly.  I am reading your images directly from StackOverflow.  After, I use [`rng`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html) to set the seed so that you can reproduce the same results on your end.  Setting the seed is useful because it allows you to reproduce the random pixel selection that I did.  We generate those linear indices, then create our `3 x N` matrices for both `im1` and `im2`.  Finding `A` is exactly how I described, but you're probably not used to the `rdivide` / `/` operator.  `rdivide` finds the inverse on the right side of the operator, then multiplies it with whatever is on the left side.  This is a more efficient way of doing the calculation, rather than calculating the inverse of the right side separately, then multiplying with the left when you're done.  In fact, MATLAB will give you a warning stating to avoid calculating the inverse separately and that you should the divide operators instead.  Next, I cast `im2` to `double` to ensure precision as `A` will most likely be floating point valued, then go through the multiplication of each pixel with `A` to compute the result.  That last line of code looks pretty intimidating, but if you want to figure out how I derived this, I used this to create vintage style photos which also require a matrix multiplication much like this approach and you can read up about it here:  [How do I create vintage images in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25751673/how-do-i-create-vintage-images-in-matlab/25752401#25752401) .  `out` stores our final image.  After running this code and showing what `out` looks like, this is what we get:

[image]

Now, the output looks completely scrambled, but the colour distribution more or less mimics what the input original image looks like.  I have a few explanations on why this is the case:

1. There is quantization noise.  If you take a look at the final image, there is various white spotting all over.  This is probably due to the quantization error that is introduced when compressing your image.  Pixels that should map to the same colours between the images will have slight variations due to quantization which gives us that spotting
2. There is more than one colour from `im2` that maps to `im1`.  If there is more than one colour from `im2` that maps to `im1`, it is impossible for a linear multiplication with the matrix `A` to be able to generate more than one kind of colour for `im1` given a single pixel in `im2`.  Instead, the least mean-squared solution will try and generate a colour that minimizes the error and give you the best colour possible instead.  This is probably way the face and other fine details of the image are obscured because of this exact reason.
3. The image is noisy.  Your `im2` is not completely clean.  I can also see various spots of salt and pepper noise across all of the channels.  One bad thing about this method is that if your image is subject to noise, then this method will not faithfully reconstruct the original image properly.  Your image can **only** be corrupted by a wrong mapping of colours.  Should there be any other type of image noise introduced, then this method will definitely not work as you are trying to reconstruct the original image based on a noisy image.  There are pixels in the noisy image that were never present in the original image, so you'll have no luck getting it back to the way it was before!

If you want to take a look at the histograms of each channel between the original image and the output image, this is what we get:

[image]

The code I used to generate the above figure was:

```
names = {'Red', 'Green', 'Blue'};
figure;
for idx = 1 : 3
    subplot(3,2,2*idx - 1);
    imhist(im1(:,:,idx));
    title([names{idx} ': Image 1']);
end

for idx = 1 : 3
    subplot(3,2,2*idx);
    imhist(out(:,:,idx));
    title([names{idx} ': Output']);
end
```

The left side shows the red, green and blue histograms for the original image while the right side shows the same histograms for the reconstructed image.  You can see that the general shape more or less mimics the original image, but there are some spikes throughout - most likely attributed to quantization noise and the non-unique mapping between colours of both images.

---

All in all, this is the best that I could do, but I think that was the whole point of the exercise.... to show that it isn't possible.

For more information on how to perform colour correction, check out [Richard Alan Peters' II Digital Image Processing slides on colour correction](https://ia802707.us.archive.org/23/items/Lectures_on_Image_Processing/EECE253_05_ColorCorrection.pdf).  This was what I started with, and the derivation of how to calculate `A` can be found in his slides.  Perhaps you can use some of what he talks about in your future work.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the final image is not like the im1. I used imhist() to compare the rgb colors for each chanel of out and im1. It seems that rgb colors were streched equally to the range of[0-255] but not restored like the im1 ones. the histogram of im1 is completely different of im2. Its the same image but im2 is redish. Any suggestions ? Btw it did notmalize the rgb colors to range 0 - 255 which is a plus. The only think i need to find now is how to change the histograms to match each other's...

Comment: @KostasRim - It would help if you actually posted the images themselves.  This would prevent myself (and others) to stop guessing.  Also, are you **sure** you performed histogram matching properly?  Did you do it separately for all three channels?  Try my edit and see.

Comment: @KostasRim - Perhaps using a combination of normalizing the colours **as well as histogram matching**?  Try doing what I suggested first, followed by one of my other suggestions in my edit and see what you get.

Comment: First of all i want to thank you for all of your good info. To our topic now, i have used histeq before and it didnt work. I tried histeq again with imhist arguement and the histograms kinda matched but the colors weren't right. I will post the two pictures so you can tell me what you think. Btw the im2 has noise added. Don't worry about it, i know how to remove it ;p

Comment: i also removed the noise, the second image is im2!

Comment: No worries. Thanks! I have the images now so I'll try. I'll edit my post again when or if I solve your problem. Stay tuned!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need a scaling function to map the values of `im2` to the values of `im1`. 
This is fairly simple and you could write a scaling function to have it available for any such case. 
A basic scaling mapping would work as follows:

```
out_value = min_output + (in_value - min_input) * (outrange / inrange)
```

given that there is an input value `in_value` that is within a range of values `inrange=max_input-min_input` and the mapping results an output value `out_value` within a range `outrange=max_output-min_output`. We also need to take into account the minimum input and output range bounds (`min_input` and `min_output`) to have a correct mapping.
See for example the following code for a scaling function:

```
%
% scale the values of a matrix using a set of limits
% possible ways to use:
% y = scale( x, in_range, out_range)  --> ex. y = scale( x, [8 230], [0 255])
% y = scale( x, out_range)            --> ex. y = scale( x, [0 1])
% 
function y = scale( x, varargin );
    if nargin<2,
        error([upper(mfilename),':: Syntax: y=',mfilename,'(x[,in_range],out_range)']);
    end;
    if nargin==2,
        inrange=[min(x(:)) max(x(:))];      % compute the limits of the input variable
        outrange=varargin{1};               % get the output limits from the arguments
    else
        inrange=varargin{1};                % get the input limits from the arguments
        outrange=varargin{2};               % get the output limits from the arguments
    end;

    if diff(inrange)==0,                    % row or column vector matrix or scalar
        % just do a clipping...
        if x>=outrange(2), 
            y=outrange(2); 
        elseif x<=outrange(1), 
            y=outrange(1); 
        else 
            y=x; 
        end;
    else
        % actually scale the data
        % using: out = min_output + (x-min_input) * (outrange / inrange)
        y = outrange(1) + (x-inrange(1))*abs(diff(outrange))/abs(diff(inrange));
    end;
```

This function gets a matrix of values and scales them to a desired range.
In your case it could be used as following (variable `img` is the scaled `im2`):

```
for i=1:size(im1,3),        % for each of the input/output image channels
    output_range = [min(min(im1(:,:,i))) max(max(im1(:,:,i)))];
    img(:,:,i) = scale( im2(:,:,i), output_range);
end;
```

This way `im2` is scaled to the range of values of `im1` one channel at a time. Output variable `img` should be the desired one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried to scale it but the result image was not  the same as im1.

Comment: @KostasRim are you sure you got it right? I have already tested it and works fine. All tables are double [0...255]. Double is a must. Depending on the values it might be possible to have round-off errors due to the divisions but it should occur to the 9th++ digit.

Comment: @KostasRim ok now that I saw the images that you include in the question I believe that the problem is much more complex. In general if you had a knowledge of the initial transformation that led to the degraded image, and if it were reversible, then it would be possible to reverse it, given the quantization errors due to the integer nature of data.

Comment: @KostaRim but if you have no knowledge of the degradation mapping (including the fact that you do not know that it is linear) then supposing a linear transformation to reverse it is not enough...

Comment: yeah, i have no idea what transformations led to the final image. The whole point is to reverse it. I found two ways to do it, first is using histeq for each color channel.The output photo was quite good, very close to im1 colors but slightly glowish in the middle. Althought the histograms were not so close. The other method is the one that was posted here. The colors and the histogram became similar but not the image. I will include both of theese answers to my excercise and hope i get a good grade :). Thanks!